# Cellbased maps explanation?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to understand cellbased maps and how they work, i have googled alot but can't seem to find any explanation for it.

With cell based maps i mean the ones where you do height and everything like walls roof floor in each cell.
If possible i would appreciate an explanation from a Javascript perspective, but only a theoretical explanation can do.

So why do we use them? how do they work?
Is it just like a normal array with more information?

Comment: Sorry, the internet is a bit dry on the topic, but if you could tell me exactly what a cell based map is I'll tell you how it works, why and how to use it etc.

Comment: It wouldn't be just a fancy word for completely plain and ordinary array maps?

Comment: Actually, why do you ask? It's just a fancy word after all, it doesn't even matter whether the maps you make fit the description or not, as long as they do the job you want them to.

Comment: The cellbased maps as i understand so far is where each "node" is a cell with information about everyting in/on that node such as walls, floor, roof, and items. Seems to be the way to do tilebased maps, but i can't find any good documentation about it. No matter how i formulate the query on google.

Comment: Well, just look up tile maps, no reason getting worked up about this specific word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most commonly tile based games mix two types of data to make the game world.

1. A tile grid with information that every tile needs to have like texturing, accessibility, height, two of the four adjacent possible walls and depending on the game perhaps some other stuff.
2. All the stuff that can move, or is complex to represent. This is usually made as individual objects containing all their own properties, including position coordinates. You store these objects on one or multiple lists. Often it will be advantageous to have links from the tiles to the objects occupying it.

A small sketch:

```
grid=[]
for(a=0;a<100;a++){
    grid[a]=[]
    for(b=0;b<100;b++){
        grid[a][b]={} //one object for every tile, stuff in all the info you need
    }
}
character={}
character.x=3
character.y=4
misc=[] //list of case 2 objects
misc[misc.length]=character
grid[character.x][character.y].occupant=character //backwards reference
```

Comment: Nice just what i was looking for.

Comment: Remember to mark it as 'answered'

Comment: And do remember, it's just one of many possible setups, needs vary from game to game, it won't fit everything.

Comment: Yeah but its a good enough start. :) thx